# Array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'

Tags: c

```
//transpose of a martrix
// if [1][2] transposed of it is [2][1]
#include<stdio.h>
void transpose(int num[][],int x,int y);
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int num[10][10];
    printf("What type of matrix you want to working with(x,y)?\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    //lets the matrix numbers
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)//for how many row
    {
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++)//for the colume in the matrix
        {
            printf("Data for matrix[%d][%d]:)\n",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&num[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    //printing the data in the form of the matrix
    /* like [0][0]   [0][1] .....  
             line 27 (printf("\n"));
            [1][0]   [1][1]......*/
    printf("The data in the matrix form is :\n");
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");//this is for the line gap for the martix after a loop is completed.
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",num[i][j]);
        }
    }
    transpose(num,x,y);
    return 0;

}

void transpose(int num[][], int x, int y)
{
    int tranpose[10][10];//to stores the trnaspose matrix
    for( int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            tranpose[i][j]=num[j][i];//just exchange the matrix range.eg [1][2 as [2][1]]
        }
    }
    //for the display for the transpose matrix 
    printf("\n");
    printf("The tranpose matrix is :\n");
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");//this is for the line gap for the martix after a loop is completed.
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",tranpose[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

I tried a program to find the tranpose of th martix inputed by the user.I check all the error point but the problem is not executing .
Error Message are:
1.array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'.
2. declaration of 'num' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first.

What I need to solve this error.

Comment: The compiler cannot index `int num[][]`. It has to know the inner dimension(s) – so you can only omit the outer (first) dimension, which is what (2) tells you.

Comment: You can just do `int num[10][10]`. It's uncool to accept a fixed size, but you already have a fixed size in `main`, so...

Comment: OT: Please avoid naming local variables the same as the function they are defined in. That's confusing and makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

As an argument `int num[][]` is invalid. The inner array need a size.

Thankfully C have *variable-length arrays* and a syntax that allows you to specify the size as variables, including arguments. That requires changing the order of your arguments though:

```
void transpose(size_t x, size_t y, int num[x][y]);
```

---

Also note that I changed the type of the size arguments.